# How come I can't use Screen on a different computer?

Tags: linux, unix, login, remote, gnu-screen

When I use putty, login and type "screen", it works.

When I use a DIFFERENT computer--a linux based system. I SSH into it through my local machine.
Then, I type "screen" , and it displays this error?:

```
'cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' -please check
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/116775/sudo-as-different-user-and-running-screen/116830#116830

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably `su`'d to a user different than one you logged in as.  You must run `screen` as the same user which owns the terminal device, which is the user you logged in as.

If you need to run commands as another user, start your screen and do your "`su`" from inside it.

Comment: i get the same error message when i `su` to a non-privileged user (other than the one i logged in as) and try to run screen.

Comment: @quack: Uh, yes...?  You are not contributing any new information, here.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: @Teddy: Yes, I did su to the user different than one logged in. If so, can I still use screen?

Comment: @Alex: Not like that.  But you can start your screen and do your "`su`" inside it.

Comment: @Teddy: just verifying your diagnosis, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Is the machine on which you are having problems known to be particularly "locked down"?

It seems like it might be a permissions problem with your pseudo-terminal. After getting this error message, check the output of **ls -l */dev/pts/0*** (use the path from the error message). If it does not show you as the owner with read and write bits, then you may check it out with the machine's administrator.

I can imagine a system that would chown-away and chmod-down a pseudo-terminal after the initial login process gets going (sub-processes could inherit the already open file handles for std{in,out,err}), but that would be pretty draconian. What does **mount | grep pts** show? Maybe the mount options are setup incorrectly…

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reattach the session that was started elsewhere? If so, and the other session hasn't dettached, you need to do `screen -d -r <sessionname>`.

If it's *merely* starting `screen`, then I'm not sure.